# I tried to install react-native-agora but unfortuatly when i link the react native agora the app does't build

Tags: react-native

I tried to install react-native-agora but unfortuatly when i link the react native agora the app does't build.

Error Message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34 is also present at [:react-native-agora] AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-35 value=(true).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
android:allowBackup="true"
```

Add these 2 lines to your AndroidManifest.xml file in 'project-root>>android>>app>>src>>debug>>' within the <application /> tag